# DHTML pop up window displaying compatbility mode in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, dhtml

I have the below piece of javascript code in my dot net application.

```
try { JSON } catch (e) { alert("Compatibility Mode Detected") }
```

My application is currently running in IE8. It is not in compatibility mode. Even though my application is not running in compatibility mode I am getting the above mentioned popup whenever I try to display a page through DHTML window.

Comment: Are you *certain* that you're not in compatibility mode? Can you prove it? Or maybe you're even in quirks mode? It's fairly clear you're not in standards mode, even if you think you are, because the JSON object wouldn't throw an error like that in IE8 standards mode.

Comment: I am sure about that cos i manually changed that.. also m not getting that popup when i m opening other pages but it is happening only for pages which am trying to open in DHTML window.